# Flutter not loading images that failed to load the first time

Tags: flutter

Switch airplane on mode and navigate to a StatefulWidget that includes a NetworkImage. The image fails to load since there is no connectivity. Now switch on airplane mode off. The image doesn't load. Navigating to another view and back again also doesn't help. Minimizing the app doesn't help, but restarting it completely does.

How would you resolve this? How do I make Flutter try to reload the image connectivity is regained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [flutter_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_image) plugin and use `NetworkImageWithRetry`.

Comment: So this lead me to "flutter_advanced_networkimage", which I ended up using in the end. But it's definitely a correct and useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of trying all image plugins and answers on stackoverflow. I realized the error goes away when I go back and come back to same screen. So I retried loading images 3 times.

```
                          CachedNetworkImage(
                          key: ValueKey(imageUrl
                              .split),
                          placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2),
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => CachedNetworkImage(
                              key: ValueKey(imageUrlsplit +
                                  'retry1'),
                              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2), child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => CachedNetworkImage(key: ValueKey(imageUrlsplit + 'retry2'), placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2), child: CircularProgressIndicator()), errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Text(error.toString()), imageUrl: imageUrlsplit),
                              imageUrl: imageUrlsplit),
                          imageUrl: imageUrlsplit)
```